# about doing UI test using selenium-rc for internet explore 7 under Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-7, selenium-rc

Excuse me, may I ask if any one have tried to use selenium rc to do UI test for Inernet Explore 7 under window vista?

I have tried to do that. But the result is that: when the code is run, it gets the IE7 opened and the page loaded. Afterwards, it does nothing although I do have command for typing text and clicking buttons after the page load.

When I run the same code for Firefox 3.5, it does not have such problem.

May I ask what may be the possible problem for this?

Answer (score 1):

Turn protected mode off and you shouldn't have a problem!